# Looking for monitoring tool for app sales and trends - combining iTunes App Store and Android Market

Tags: software-recommendation, ios-appstore, android

I am currently on the search for a universal desktop application (osx if possible) that is tracking both my iOS developer account as well as my android market store account.

I already tried a lot of different tools but none of them so far seemed to work this way:

- Prismo (OS X / only iOS / lots of bugs)
- AppViz (OS X / afaik only iOS / though decent tool)
- AppAnnie (Web / only iOS / does not give all stats wanted / not sure but data privacy)
- Distimo Monitoring Tool (Web / multiple Stores / data privacy not given)
- AppFigures (I did not try this so far - anyone have experience with this tool?)

If anyone would know such a tool as Distimo but with the privacy and data security that is needed for highly confidential app statistics it would be awesome if you could post it right here.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of small and big developers use Distimo Monitor, most probably because they like the feature set, number of supported stores and ad networks and also because they trust the data privacy and security. Just give it a try, for questions you can always use the contact form.

Answer (score 1):

Appfigures has worked very well for me. I pay for an account (you need to pay a little if you have more than a certain number of apps, or want to receive a  daily status email) Their service handles iOS and Android (and probably others)

I also have a free account with App Annie which I use mainly for user reviews around the world (their status reports are in dollars, and I work in pounds, or I might have used them instead)

App Figures have just added user reviews too, so I can probably cancel App Annie now.